# Neo4j "Tried to execute Write query after executing Schema modification" Error

Tags: java, database, neo4j, driver

I'm using the latest version of Neo4j and the Java driver and keep getting the following error with my code:

> Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Tried to execute Write query after executing Schema modification

And here's my code:

```
import org.neo4j.driver.*;

public class HelloWorldExample implements AutoCloseable
{
    private final Driver driver;

    public HelloWorldExample( String uri, String user, String password )
    {
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, AuthTokens.basic( user, password ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception
    {
        driver.close();
    }

    public void printGreeting( final String message )
    {
        try ( Session session = driver.session() )
        {
            String greeting = session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public String execute( Transaction tx )
                {
                  //ISSUE HERE
                    String test = "CREATE INDEX qwert IF NOT EXISTS FOR (m:Pode) ON (m.made)";
                    Result hello = tx.run(test);
                    String test2 = "CREATE(n:Node)";
                    Result hello2 = tx.run(test2);
                 //ISSUE ABOVE
                    return "";
              //      return result.single().get( 0 ).asString();
                }
            } );
            System.out.println( greeting );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String... args ) throws Exception
    {
        try ( HelloWorldExample greeter = new HelloWorldExample( "bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "Neo4J" ) )
        {
            greeter.printGreeting( "hello, world" );
        }
    }
}
```

I know the error is happening at the "ISSUE HERE" part, and if I remove either of the "CREATE" lines, it goes away, but I need both lines, and not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicated that you can't combine a schema and a write query in a single transaction.

Split the two queries into two transactions.
In the first transaction define the index, and then in the second transaction create a node.